# Делаю ajax запрос для асинхронной подгрузки списка, но не приходит список

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Я хочу сделать подгрузку списка асинхронно как в вк лента подгружается, только тут список из кучи анимаций для игры и все их разом не показать, я сделал отображение первых 2 тысяч анимаций, а дальше сделал скрипт который отсылает запрос ajax и удаляет предыдущую тысячу анимаций и ждет когда ему дадут новую тысячу, таким образом всегда есть 2 тысячи анимаций и можно вернуться к прошлой тысячи без подгрузки лишней. Но вот только я сделал запрос и мне вернулся код страницы, я отобразил его в консоли и там список был пуст, хотя jQuery код его должен был загрузить, и я проверял, он загружается, просто долго. И вот вопросы:
1. Что не так со списком?
2. Как из исходного кода выдрать только содержимое select?
Вот что мне приходит:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="animations.js"></script>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select class="list" size="10"></select>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="handler.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Что не так со списком?" - Вы видите в Вашем вопросе список? Я - нет. Кто может сказать, что с ним не так, не видя его? Никто.

Comment: Добавил что приходит

Comment: Где тут список? Это html самодостаточной страницы.

Comment: <select class="list" size="10"></select> в нем должен быть список анимаций

Comment: Нет, не должен. Это всего лишь текст. Никакой javascript в нем не выполняется.

Comment: Я сделал html, к нему подключил handler.js который из animations.js берет гиганский массив и выдерает 1000 анимаций и вставляет их в список, если зайти на этот html то он отобразит весь этот список как надо, а вот когда делаю ajax запрос его нет.

Comment: Поразмышляйте над моим предыдущим комментарием. ("выд**и**рает")

Comment: Если "animations.js" у Вас уже на клиенте, зачем нужен ajax?

Comment: Моя цель была сделать асинхронную подгрузку анимаций, а если я получу js код по ajax то это разве будет асинхронно тогда выполнятся? Я хотел бы чтобы он выполнился и отправил мне результат уже. Как мне тогда сделать запрос чтобы получить уже результат js? А еще как выдрать select со всем списком нужным из этой кучи текста?

Comment: Извините, я не понимаю Вашего потока слов. Какие анимации? "Я хотел бы чтобы он выполнился и отправил" - кто "он" и  куда "отправил"? Работайте над формулировками.

Comment: В animations.js находится массив анимаций для игры. Эту страницу я буду отображать в игре, когда юзер выберает анимацию она включается у него. Но анимаций так много что все их не отобразить, а через 1 js загружать если то лагает, т.к. процесс не легкий. Я хочу сделать обработку массива через сервер который будет сам обрабатывать это все и отсылать готовый результат с списком анимаций

Comment: "animations.js" всегда одинаковый?

Comment: Да, там чисто массив анимаций который не меняется

Comment: тогда Вам не нужен никакой ajax

Comment: У вас все анимации на клиенте в массиве, находящемся в animations.js. Насколько я понимаю, это какие-то функции с названием анимации? Список строится на основании этих функций-анимаций. Вы хотите чтобы сервер вам генерировал список, в котором можно выбрать и запустить выбранную анимацию. Но, все анимации у вас уже на клиенте есть, почему бы на клиенте не сгенерировать этот список?